# Posit algorithm in android opencv

Tags: android, opencv, tracking, augmented-reality

I have been looking online and in the android opencv source code, but I cannot figure where the Posit algorithm opencv methods are. Does anyone know where they are in the source code of opencv?

I checked where the following link claims it to be:

https://code.google.com/p/viewercv/source/browse/android-opencv/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/posit.cpp?r=fdcf3fdbac4cccbb0eefd55db5c8acd86ca78bb7

but i still could not find it. Does anyone know how I can use the code in the link to build it myself? Hopefully I am just overlooking something in the android opencv.

I cannot find cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2() either.

**Update

cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2 has been renamed to solvePnP in the c++ implementation of opencv; however, I still do not know where the posit algorithm is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SolvePnp in opencv does everything I need from the posit algorithm